# Filter and conditions

Tags: mysql, list, conditional-statements, exists

I have a table for example clients with a column as doc_number, and I also have a list of client documents that I dont know if they exist in the client table.

The question is, is there any easy way to get all de the clientes that are in this list and not in the table?

I don't want to use a auxiliary table, thanks!

Comment: try to clarify your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write your own function

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `filter_clients`(InString Varchar(1000)) RETURNS varchar(1000) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN

  # loop to divide string list by comma

  # select for each string segment

  # add result to Outstring.i

RETURN OutString;
END
```

and call it later with

```
SELECT filter_clients('123456, 1234658, 145678')
```

I wouldn't do that and divide the list in some other language

Comment: May be I wasn't clear, but I dont have a second table just a list of documents like this (123456, 1234658, 145678), but much longer!

Comment: if the question is which of (123456, 1234658, 145678) is not in the client table then I would split the list outside of MySQL in your programming language of choice and then run SQL checks on each number. It is possible to write an SQL function that loops through the list within MySQL, but that's easier done outside.

Comment: the idea is to do somethig more simple, I could create a temporary table and make a right outer join there. BUt thats exactlly what I don't want to do :)

Comment: what programming language do you use outside of mysql?

Comment: using a function seems to be the best solutions, as it could be used in other cases. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a derived table:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 2000 AS doc_number
  UNION ALL SELECT 2001
  UNION ALL SELECT 2002
  UNION ALL SELECT 2003
  UNION ALL SELECT 2004
  UNION ALL SELECT 2005
  UNION ALL SELECT 2006
) b
WHERE b.doc_number NOT IN (SELECT doc_number FROM client)
```

Just open a spreadsheet and make the "union all select ..." with the list of documents.